# How to specify foreign keys between two DataTables in SQL Bulk Copy operation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

I have two DataTables A and B. A is the parent table. Rows in B contain a field ParentId that references A.

I want to bulk insert A and B separately. After inserting A, how do I set the ParentId in the corresponding child rows in B?

Update:

I have the following code for creating the DataTables:

```
    var a= new DataTable("A");

    DataColumn id= new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
    billablePriceMapId.AutoIncrement = true;
    billable.Columns.Add(id);

    DataColumn fee = new DataColumn("Fee", typeof(decimal));
    billable.Columns.Add(fee);

    DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
    keys[0] = id;
    billable.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

For the child table:

```
    var b= new DataTable("B");

    DataColumn id= new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
    billablePriceMapId.AutoIncrement = true;
    billable.Columns.Add(id);

    DataColumn parentId= new DataColumn("ParentId", typeof(int));
    billable.Columns.Add(parentId);

    DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
    keys[0] = id;
    billable.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

I have not set up any relationship between the two tables. I would like to know how I could do that the right way.

Following is the code that I use for bulk insert:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.A";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(a);

                            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.B";
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(b);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Logger.Error(ex, "Bulk copy operation failed.");
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: The missing information is: table `A`'s primary key is an [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) column, correct? Do you have the ID's that should be inserted or do you want to let the database generate them fo you?

Comment: Could you perhaps show us what you've attempted so far, as long with some example data? Off the bat, I would recommend generating the Id before the time, and not having the B.ParentID field as an identify, and A.Id not as an identity either.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have added more information to the question. Please check them. A's primary key is an auto increment field. I want the database to generate the Ids for me.

Comment: @WynDiesel Please check the added information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use the identity to link the two tables, rather, I would use a GUID to link them. Like this :

```
var a= new DataTable("A");

DataColumn guid= new DataColumn("Guid", typeof(Guid));
billable.Columns.Add(Guid.NewGuid());

DataColumn id= new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
billablePriceMapId.AutoIncrement = true;
billable.Columns.Add(id);

DataColumn fee = new DataColumn("Fee", typeof(decimal));
billable.Columns.Add(fee);

DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
keys[0] = id;
billable.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

And then for the children

```
var b= new DataTable("B");

DataColumn id= new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int));
billablePriceMapId.AutoIncrement = true;
billable.Columns.Add(id);

DataColumn parentId= new DataColumn("ParentGuid", typeof(Guid));
billable.Columns.Add(parentGuid);

DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
keys[0] = id;
billable.PrimaryKey = keys;
```

This means that you know what the link will be before inserts, before the identify is generated.

Answer (score 0):

`SqlBulkCopy` doesn't return the identity values. So unless your table `A` have another unique column such as a "Code" to allow to perfect a `SELECT` you will not be able to retrieve the generated identity values.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Bulk Operations](http://bulk-operations.net/)

This library is not free but allows to output identity values. It uses under the hood `SqlBulkCopy` with `Temporary Table` to allow this feature

```
using (var bulkCopy = new BulkOperation(connection))
{
    bulkCopy.Transaction = transaction;
    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.A";

    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", ColumnMappingDirectionType.Output);
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col1");
    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col2");
    bulkCopy.BulkInsert(a);

    // Copy identity value in `Id` from table A to `ParentId` in table B
    // ...code...
}
```